# Uploading a file from client system to server using jquery ajax request from html file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, file

I am uploading a file to my server from client system.  The place i struck is,

this is the html code,

```
<input type="file" name="fileCarRes" id="fileCarRes" size="10" />
```

and using this jquery ajax request i am taking this file to another php file then with use of PHP function i will upload the file. The Jquery code i am using is,

```
file = $('#fileCarRes').val();
url="careers.php";

    $.post
    (
        url,
        {
            'act'           :   'file',
            'file'          :    file
        },
        function (responseText)
        {
            alert(responseText);
        },
        "html"
    );

In php file

if(isset($_POST['act']) && $_POST['act'] == 'file')
    {
        $file           =   $_POST['file'];


                 $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
        } etc...
```

In PHP `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` is used for getting the file from the html file.  Now i am send and ajax query without using the `<form>`.  So i dont know, how to map the file path to this PHP function.  I am working in MVC architechture.

'Thanks in Advance !!'